# Choosing numbering on equations

Tags: equations, numbering

I'm writing some course notes and through out I want to refer to the equation number in the book we are using, rather than numbering the equations within the document. In other words **how can I decide for myself what the equation number should be?** I've made a MWE below, but the problem is that it puts the equation number on the next line below the equation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
The density of states at $ \epsilon $ is
\begin{center}
$D_{e}(\epsilon)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\left(\dfrac{2m_{e}}
{\hbar^{2}}\right)^{3/2}\left(\epsilon-
E_{c}\right)^{1/2}$\end{center}\begin{flushright}\textrm{(8.37)}\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image: I want the equation number to be on line with the equation]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\tag` and an `equation` environment:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
The density of states at $ \epsilon $ is
\begin{equation}
D_{e}(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\biggl( \dfrac{2m_{e}}
{\hbar^{2}} \biggr)^{3/2} (\epsilon - E_{c} )^{1/2}
\tag{8.37}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I didn't use the `\left`, `\right` construct but the `\biggl`, `\biggr` commands instead.

If you have access to the original .tex document in which the equation appears, you could use the [`xr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xr) package to help you cross-reference the external expressions.

You could be interested in the following documents to help you typeset math expressions:

- The [`user guide`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) for the `amsmath`  package.
- The [`mathmode`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathmode) document.

Answer (score 0):

Just added to give a solution with better spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}

\begin{document}

The density of states at $\epsilon$ is
\begin{equation}
  D_{e}(\epsilon)
  = \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}
    \mleft(\frac{2m_{e}}{\hbar^{2}}\mright)^{3/2}
    (\epsilon - E_{c})^{1/2}
    \tag{8.37}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Instead of adding the two instructions `\mkern -4mu` by hand to obtain better spacing, one could load the `mleftright` package and use `\mleft` and `\mright` instead of `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @Mico I didn't knew of that package; thanks for the pointer.